# why when ever I execute “PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()” my application blocked

Tags: java, mysql

when ever I execute a jdbc statement my java application blocked {NOT STOPPED} Here is my java code

```
RHsysConnection con = new RHsysConnection();
PreparedStatement connection
       = con.getConnection("INSERT INTO `Contrat`(`IdE`, `Type`, `Ddebut`, `Dfin`, `DurreEss`, `Observation`, `EssT`, `ContT`)"
                           + "VALUES(? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,?)");

connection.setInt(1, this.IdE);
connection.setString(2, this.type);
connection.setString(3,new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(this.ddebut));
if(this.dfin==null)
    connection.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
else
    connection.setString(4, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(this.dfin));
connection.setInt(5, this.durreEss);
connection.setString(6, this.observation);
connection.setString(7, this.essT);
connection.setString(8, this.contT);

int executeUpdate = connection.executeUpdate();
```

but when I set the values manually like this

```
...
connection.setInt(1, 2);
connection.setString(2, "CDD");
connection.setString(3,"2016-12-12");
connection.setString(4, "2017-12-11");
connection.setInt(5, 1);
connection.setString(6, null);
connection.setString(7, "N");
connection.setString(8, "N");
...
```

the application runs perfectly same help please

Comment: try to wrap your code with try catch and read if any exception over there ?

Comment: At which point the application is blocked?

Comment: Please don't post *Java* code as if it's a *Javascript* runnable snippet. I've removed the snippet tags now, but it would be better not to include them to start with.

Comment: I do try it but my app just blocked when I add the **connection.setInt(1, this.IdE);** without any outputs or errors or any thing

Comment: ok jon skeet tanks

Comment: Why are you calling your `PreparedStatement` variable `connection`? That's really confusing... it's very odd that you're calling `getConnection()` for what would normally be `prepareStatement`, too. What is `RHsysConnection`?

Comment: `RHsysConnection` the class that make the connection to the database and it has the method `getConnection()`

Comment: @TahaElmahdaoui I'm sorry but informations you give are not complete to understand your problem. I suggest you to review what you have done until now and specify well which code runs and which not.